# function calling another function will not work

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following functions:

```
function boom(){
    alert("first call");
}
function bang(){
    boom();
    alert("?");
}
```

They are simple alerts but for some reason when i call the function bang nothing happens.Any ideas?

Comment: And how are you calling it? Any errors in the console? Is that the real code?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/srz0v5b3/ The problem is somewhere else. Try to come up with a complete example that demonstrates the problem. Or debug it yourself, look in the browser's error console and see if there are any errors.

Comment: I am using the body onload but i don't get any errors

Comment: Avoid using alerts. Learn to use your browser's `console` tab. F12 in Firefox and Chrome. Then switch the `alert()` to `console.log()` statements. Will make your life easier.

Comment: POP UP BLOCKER! Do not use alerts for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Guys for some reason my problem was resolved by refreshing the page.Before refreshing nothing was working

Comment: So, you had checked the option not to open more windows from the page in the alert?

Comment: There's a checkbox in the alert window (not in IE though), by checking it you can prevent the alerts from that page untill refreshed.

Comment: I think you might be right